# Get a Kerberos service ticket from the command line

Tags: command-line, kerberos

I am in the process of debugging a Kerberos setup. I have a valid `krb5.conf` and I can call `kinit USERNAME` to get a Ticket Granting Ticket (TGT):

```
Credentials cache: /root/krb5cc_root
Default principal: USERNAME@EXAMPLE.COM
Number of entries: 1

[1] Service principal: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        Valid starting: Wednesday, June 4, 2014 at 10:02:29 PM
        Expires: Thursday, June 5, 2014 at 8:02:29 AM
```

I would like to use that TGT to request a Kerberos **service ticket** on the command line, so I can look at it with klist. It will help with debugging a Kerberos problem I am trying to solve.

Is there a command or program to retreive a Kerberos service ticket for a given service ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**`kvno service`**

> acquires  a  service ticket for the specified Kerberos principals and prints out the key version numbers

Comment: With heimdal, it is `kgetcred`